# Inconsistent font size on the UI (for some .blend files)

Tags: interface, resolution, font

I bought a course online and downloaded its sample files. But when I open them in Blender, the interface looks weird:

[image]

As you can see, the text on property panels are huge, and the ones on Outliner are tiny. It's not the case for my own files:

[image]

UI font size shouldn't be file-dependent... or they are? How can I change it? (I checked `Preference -> Resolution Scale` and `Theme -> Text Style`. They're 100% the same for both files.)

Comment: you can change the size of the font in the editor you want, I think it's Ctrl + MMB

Comment: @moonboots It works! Well... for everything except Outliner. Perhaps there is a keymapping conflict or something...

Comment: No I think it is unavailable ATM in outliner. Shortcut alternatively  numpad +/- over props, ctrl - numpad +/- in text editor / py console .. but in outliner it expands / contracts hierarchy.

Comment: Blender loads the UI settings & layout from the blend file by default. In the preferences, you can disable this: Load & Save (tab) > Blend File (section) > Load UI (checkbox). Perhaps it helps?